# jQuery - check which element was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a function that does a specific job. But I don't want to repeat that function over and over just to change the `classes` at my `click` function. So I thought, the code would look much cleaner if I add all these `classes` to my function. But the problem is: How can I detect which element I am clicking. In this case, let's say I clicked `.firstRowLeftTable`. How do I add some `HTML` only to my `.first` class

```js
$(".firstRowLeftTable .addFurcation, .secondRowLeftTable .addFurcation").click(function() {
    $(".first>div:nth-child("+($(this).index()+1)+")").html(...); // If "firstRowLeftTable" was clicked, add some HTML only to this element
    $(".second>div:nth-child("+($(this).index()+1)+")").html(...);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the click event property `target`

```
#(".first>div").on("click", foo);

var foo = (e) => {
  var elem = e.target;
}
```